# Method encodes all less than (<) characters in a HTML string, but not the HTML tags

Tags: c#, strings, html, escaping

I am cleaning a HTML string to encode the less than sign (<) to a HTML entity (`&lt;`), but leaving the HTML tags as they are. An example is converting `"<div>Total < 500</div>"` to `"<div>Total &lt; 500</div>"`.

There's a number of posts addressing this including:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464686/html-entity-encode-text-only-not-html-tag, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245066/encode-html-in-asp-net-c-sharp-but-leave-tags-intact, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301206/how-to-encode-special-characters-in-html-but-exclude-tags
Each post points to using the Html Agility Pack and specifically the `HtmlEntity.Entitize(html)` method. This doesn't work for me because it actually ignores the < and & signs and using the above example, the output was the same as the input! I may be missing the point of how to use this method, but the code was simply this:

```
public static string EntitizeHtml( this string html )
{
   return HtmlEntity.Entitize( html );
}
```

I decided to write my own method to find the less than symbols and convert them to the HTML entity equivalent. It works, but it seems very clunky (a loop inside a loop and lots of string manipulation). I avoided Regex to keep it faster and more readable. I fully appreciate that manipulating HTML strings is often fraught with problems thanks to differing HTML versions and malformed HTML, but for my purpose this method solves my problem based on a discrete set of HTML tags. The following method will convert `"<div>Total < 500</div>"` to `"<div>Total &lt; 500</div>"` as expected.

If anyone can improve the efficiency of this method I'd be very grateful.

```
        public static string EncodeLessThanEntities( this string html )
        {
            if( !html.Contains( "<" ) )
            {
                return html;
            }

            // get the full html length
            int length = html.Length;
            // set a limit on the tag string to compare to reduce the 
            // string size (i.e. the longest tags are <center> and <strong>)
            int tagLength = 6;
            // gather all the included html tags to check
            string s = "div|span|p|br|ol|ul|li|center|font|strong|em|sub|sup";
            string[] tags = s.Split( '|' ).ToArray( );
            // find all the indices of the less than entity or tag
            var indices = AllIndexesOf( html, "<" );
            // initiate a list of indices to be replaced
            var replaceable = new List<int>( );

            // loop through the indices
            foreach( var index in indices )
            {
                // store the potential tag (up to the tag length)
                if( length - ( index + 1 ) < tagLength ) tagLength = length - ( index + 1 );
                string possibleTag = html.Substring( index + 1, tagLength );
                // automatically ignore any closing tags
                if( possibleTag.Substring( 0, 1 ) == "/" )
                {
                    continue;
                }

                bool match = false;

                // loop through each html tag to find a match
                foreach( var tag in tags )
                {
                    if( possibleTag.StartsWith( tag ) )
                    {
                        match = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if( !match )
                {
                    // if there is no match to a html tag, store the index
                    replaceable.Add( index );
                }
            }

            if( replaceable?.Any( ) ?? false )
            {
                // loop through each index and replace the '<' with '&lt;'
                foreach( var index in Enumerable.Reverse( replaceable ) )
                {
                    html = html.ReplaceAt( index, 1, "&lt;" );
                }
            }

            return html;
        }


        public static List<int> AllIndexesOf( this string input, string value )
        {
            List<int> indexes = new List<int>( );

            if( string.IsNullOrEmpty( value ) )
            {
                return indexes;
            }

            for( int index = 0; ; index += value.Length )
            {
                index = input.IndexOf( value, index );
                if( index == -1 )
                {
                    return indexes;
                }
                indexes.Add( index );
            }
        }


        public static string ReplaceAt( this string str, int index, int length, string replace )
        {
            return str.Remove( index, Math.Min( length, str.Length - index ) ).Insert( index, replace );
        }
```

I'm hoping there is a way to make the above method more efficient. Or maybe this is as good as it gets? I know there are a lot of very smart guys out there with a lot more experience and I don't include myself in that group!

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview! Have you tested your implementation against other inputs as well?

Comment: did you try `HtmlEntity.Entitize(html, true, true);` e.g. for inner HTML of the tag pair? Btw, `<div>Total < 500</div>` isn't valid HTML, probably de-entitizing problem. It's better to fix such HTML source first.

Comment: What about `a` tag, or `img`, maybe `table`?...`thead`, `tbody`, `th`, `tr`, `td`, `b`, `i`, finally `html`, `head`, `body`, `meta`, `title`, `script`, `style`, [another tags](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_byfunc.asp)? Also the solution at least isn't compartible with HTML5 because any single word can be HTML a valid tag e.g. `<aepot>some text</aepot>` is valid HTML5.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the welcome! I've tested this extensively against many inputs and I have now fixed the source HTML from this point on. The issue is that I am dealing with a few instances of malformed HTML from historical records. The set of tags I am dealing with are discrete and based on a WYSIWYG editor input so these tags are the only ones that I need to evaluate.

Comment: Additionally, I acknowledge that my solution is 100% not bulletproof given the possibility of a user typing in text (not HTML) such as '<Parts', but this is a very low risk and one that can be easily dealt with. In simple terms, the method catches those highly unusual cases of malformed HTML input and then has about a 98% chance of fixing it. Very low risk, but good QA (i.e. better than nothing).

Comment: Thanks @aepot, I actually did try `HtmlEntity.Entitize(html, true, true)` and it doesn't work to my requirements because it simply encodes everything, which is not what I need. I may as well use `HtmlEncode(html)`, which produces the same result.

Comment: No chance to fix the editor? (Or alter to something that works fine). Anyway, the code above can't guarantee the proper result as source HTML is not suitable for that. Thus, the solution can't become production-ready. That's why i can't write the code review: I can't fix it. In detailed view, it looks almost fine for me, as it intended to handle not so large texts which will consume acceprable amount of RAM. But yes, it can be somewhat optimized with no visible difference on performance (at least for texts of <1M length). As alternative solution I suggest ReGex, not better but option.

Comment: Thanks @aepot. The editor is fine. It's the historical records that are a problem. it's complicated because the data works fine in a browser, but we then use the data in a reporting tool that switches between a text display field and a html display field. Some input is text and some input is html. The report fields are dynamic so I need to work out which data fields are text and which are html and display them appropriately. I have got that working almost perfectly except for the extremely odd occasion where a user mixes html with an unencoded <. This method handles that.

Comment: OK then. Btw, i see an old syntax formatting. Old Visual Studio? Consider to update. What is .NET version? I'll try to optimize the code.

Comment: Thanks @aepot.  It's VS 2019 .and NET 4.72 and C# 7.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Every time you call `Substring`, `Remove`, `Replace` or any other method which modifies the `string`, you create new `string` instance with new memory allocation. Because `string` is immutable. All `string` operations are (relativley to numeric) are slow/expensive.  But that's OK if you keep in mind this issue and agree with it.
- `html.Contains`, `AllIndexesOf`, `foreach(var index in indices)` - 2.5 scans of the same string.
- `possibleTag.Substring(0, 1) == "/"`, why not `possibleTag[0] == '/'`? It would be faster.
- `if (replaceable?.Any() ?? false)` 1) `replaceable` cannot be `null`, then `if (replaceable.Any())` is almost fine 2) but it just check is `List` contains any elements, then `if (replaceable.Length > 0)` is better. 3) but `foreach` will not process the collection if it's empty, even `Enumerable.Reverse` call is fine for the empty collection. Thus you may wipe the `if` statement completely.
- The fastest way to construct some string from data in .NET Framework is `StringBuilder`. (.NET Core and newer .NET has `Span`-based method `string.Create` which is faster in some cases)

And finally, here's my version of the implementation

```cs
// required array can be created once per application start
private static readonly string[] tags = "div span p br ol ul li center font strong em sub sup".Split();

public static string EncodeLessThanEntities(this string html)
{
    if (html.Length < 8) // the shortest valid html is <p></p>: 7 chars but there's no room for other chars
        return html;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(html.Length); // spawn StringBuilder with initial capacity, this will reduce amount of memory allocations
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < html.Length - 2; i++)
    {
        if (html[i] == '<' && !tags.Any(tag => html.StartsWithAt(i + (html[i + 1] == '/' ? 2 : 1), tag)))
            sb.Append("&lt;");
        else
            sb.Append(html[i]);
    }
    // 'i' has value 'html.Length - 2' here, append two last chars without changes
    return sb.Append(html[i]).Append(html[i + 1]).ToString();
}

// same as `String.StartsWith` but accepts a start index
public static bool StartsWithAt(this string text, int startIndex, string value)
{
    if (text.Length - startIndex < value.Length)
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
    {
        if (text[startIndex + i] != value[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I didn't test it a lot but you may.

Comment: Thanks @aepot. This is brilliant! Not only does it work well, your explanation has given me a much greater insight and appreciation for writing better code. Thank you so much for taking the time to improve my code.